# Problems with the command delete function in applescript

Tags: keyboard, applescript

I have an applescript that I am using to clear out a huge folder. I can select all of the files but how can I indicate the "command delete" key while keeping all of the files selected? Basically after the "command a function" if I try to preform the "command delete" function it deselects all of those previously selected files.

Answer (score 1):

`keystroke "backspace" using command down`

[might be `delete` rather than `backspace` - auto-deletes are not something I want to be playing with on my first coffee of the day] ;)